# Blazor server does not start

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have tried to configure host:port without hardcoding, but the Blazor server-side app does not start in this case?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseUrls(urls: new String[] { "http://*:6000", "https://localhost:6001" });
    });
```

If I remove the call .UseUrls(urls: new String[] { "http://*:6000", "https://localhost:6001" }); it starts . What is wrong?
I see a console only with output but browser does not start

> Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Now listening on:
>   http://[::]:6000 Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Now
>   listening on: https://localhost:6001 Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime:
>   Information: Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
>   Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Hosting environment:
>   Development Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Content root
>   path: ... Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Application is
>   shutting down...